# New blog post notification has white shadow on white text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: oh noes. think of the legibility!]

All the text in `#hlinks` has a 1px white shadow, which the new blog notification probably shouldn't have.

Comment: I get the same effect. It may be appropriate to add an override in the CSS to change the text shadow colour for that one element.

Comment: Sure i pointed that out before, maybe not.. (i'm already running a ton of over-rides, so i don't see it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.